# Laravel 5.4 unable to generate csrf token in form

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am using following codes for login form -

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/admin/login']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email Id:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         {!! csrf_field() !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

But when I inspect it in browser , it is showing input field with **name="_token"** but with empty value. 
[image]
Is there anything else I am missing? Please guide.

Comment: `{!! csrf_field() !!}` -> `{{ csrf_field() }}`?

Comment: I have tried it , but no luck :(

Comment: Is it possible that there are made some changes to the laravel core or middleware by you or colleagues?

Comment: I just installed a fresh setup , let me try once more and will update. Thank you!